# Converting ILookup<DateTime,List<int>> to ILookup<DateTime,int>

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to convert  `ILookup<DateTime,List<int>> to ILookup<DateTime,int>` ?

I am creating lookup with "ToLookup" method but i am unable to create it the way I want it. I keep getting stuck with `List<int>` instead of just int's.

Alternative question (it would solve my problem too) - how should i create lookup from `IGrouping<DateTime,MyModel>`  to have `ILookup<DateTime,int>`

MyModel contains 2 integers [min,max] (for example 2,5) and i want lookup date to have all integers between them (2,3,4,5)

Edit:
My current approach is faulty.
MyModel:
DateTime Date
int min
int max

At the start i have IQueryable of MyModel.
I am trying to get all integers possible for each date as ILookup.

For example - lets say i have 2 MyModels.

```
1st
Date = 2.01.2016
min = 2
max = 5

2nd
Date = 2.01.2016
min = 9
max = 12
```

I need `Lookup<DateTime, int>` which would have <2.01.2016, <2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12>>

Comment: You should show us the original query that generated that lookup, rather than trying to convert the lookup to another.

Comment: It would help if you show the relevant parts of the `MyModel` class

Comment: How could it be a single `int` for each `DateTime`? It seems to me that you want a list of integers for each `DateTime`.

Comment: I thought that ILookup connects key with list of values if that is not the case my then i revoke my question and apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `MyModel` you can create a collection of key-value pairs that the key is the `Date` property and value goes from `min` to `max` (for this, you have to execute the query using `Linq to Objects`):

```
var pairs = models.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(
    m => Enumerable.Range(m.Min, m.Max - m.Min + 1)
                   .Select(v => new { Key = m.Date, Value = v }));
```

Then project this collection to a lookup:

```
var lookup = pairs.ToLookup(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Comment: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Int32] Range(Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `ILookup<DateTime,List<int>>` has all the `int`s you want to associate with each `DateTime`, you need to flatten your initial data first:

```
var flat = lookup1.SelectMany(i => i, (dt, num) => new {dt, num});
```

This gives you pairs of each individual `int` associated with its `DateTime`. Then you can use ToLookup to create a new Lookup from this:

```
var lookup2 = flat.ToLookup(i => i.dt, i => i.num);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the lookup of dates to numbers, you first need to generate all the possible combinations of dates and numbers. It's unclear what your source of data is but assuming it's coming from some database, you would want to sort them (lookups will be ordered in the order they are enumerated), generate the range of values, then create the lookup.

```
var orderedData =
    from x in context.MyModel
    orderby x.Date, x.Min
    select x;
var query =
    (from x in orderedData.AsEnumerable()
    from i in Enumerable.Range(x.Min, x.Max - x.Min + 1)
    select new { x.Date, i }).ToLookup(x => x.Date, x => x.i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will end up having to do 2 projections - first a selectmany to generate the ranges, then a select to let you create a normalized set to bulid your lookup from..

```
var first = new MyModel 
{
    date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1),
    min = 2,
    max = 5
};

var second = new MyModel
{
    date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1),
    min = 9,
    max = 12
};

// new []{first,second} is the placeholder for
// whatever list you're using
var normalized = new []{first, second}.SelectMany(x => 
  Enumerable.Range(x.min, x.max - x.min + 1)
    .Select(y => new {x.date, number = y}));

// this should give you {2.01.2016, <2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12>}
var lookup = normalized.ToLookup(x => x.date, y=> y.number);
```